# getSymbols.google can only get data up to 9/5/2017

Tags: r

I used this function in quantmod tool box to download daily stock data. However, recently, I found that it can download data only up to 9/5.

Does anyone else have this issue?

Here are my codes:

```
 library(quantmod)
 getSymbols.google("AAPL", globalenv(), return.class = "data.frame", from = Sys.Date()-100, to = Sys.Date())
```

Today, it is 9/8. However, I cannot see data on 9/6 and 9/7.

Comment: Using the version of quantmod on github I am getting up to Sep 7th using `getSymbols("AAPL")`

Comment: Strange. `src = "yahoo"` provides till current date - 1.